# How do I CREATE a table only if it doesn't exist in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, table, postgresql-10

This is the way to create a new table in PostgreSQL,

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    foo_id  int   PRIMARY KEY,
    bar     text,
);
```

How do I do this if it needs to check if the table already exists and to proceed with the `CREATE` only if one is not found?

Comment: I've cleaned up the question a lot in order to keep it on topic and useful for future visitors ultimately the cli only runs the command and the fact that you're using the command line and windows has nothing to do with SQL syntax you're requesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It needs to check if the table already exists and create only if not found?

There is no standards-compliant method at all, but PostgreSQL 9.1+ supports a common extension with the [`IF NOT EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) clause,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
  foo_id int PRIMARY KEY
);
```

If the table (`foo` in this case) doesn't exist, you'll get only a `NOTICE` (not an `ERROR`)

> NOTICE:  relation "foo" already exists, skipping

*Note: while the DDL `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax is non-standard, other databases like [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-create-if-not-exists.html) may also support it, and SQL Server's transact SQL supports a variant of it `IF NOT EXISTS (query) ... DDL ... GO`*